# Platformio which ESP32 board to pick

Tags: arduino, ide, esp32, platformio

Hello and happy holiday to all

I am using platformio for an arduino project for the first time. I have purchased this ESP32 borad:

**EC Buying ESP32-DevKitC Development Board ,ESP32 Development Board Equipped with WROOM-32D Module Integrated WiFi Bluetooth Module Microprocessor Interface SPI I2C I2S Suitable for Arduino**

I am new to all this and need to know what board I should pick in PLATFORMIO for this board. I have loaded the core 32 from Espressif 32 and have the large list of ESP32 boards.

just want to make sure to pick the correct board to match the one purchased. Here is also the link to amazon on the board purchased.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0B64SD16T?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B64SD16T)

Thanks to all you wonderful people who can help.

I have not tried any boards listed as I did not what to damage this new board.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about hardware selection and contains no code as required by the `arduino` tag.

Comment: It could lose the Arduino tag, there's nothing specific to Arduino. It's not about selecting hardware, though, it's about configuring a build system.

Comment: Do you think a question about setting up a Makefile would be appropriate here? If it would then I think this would as well. If not then I think it's totally fair to close this. I don't have a strong opinion either way.

Answer (score 1):

You won't damage an ESP32 by choosing the wrong PlatformIO board. The worst that will happen is that you won't be able to flash your program to the board, or it won't run correctly when it's flashed. While it's not impossible to brick an ESP32 by configuring security options, that's not something PlatformIO is going accidentally do to your board.

You can search [the list of available boards on the web](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/index.html#espressif-32) and look for a close match.

The most important thing is to get the correct processor type - figure out whether you have ESP32, ESP32-S2, ESP32-S3, ESP32-C3 (or eventually some other kind of ESP32). Only consider PlatformIO boards for that specific CPU. Then look for the size of the flash storage. Usually any board that matches that spec will work.

`esptool.py`, the program PlatformIO uses to flash the firmware to the board, will detect the CPU type, so if you have an ESP32-S2 and try to flash code for an ESP32 to it, it will detect this and report an error.

In your case you might try the generic [Espressif ESP32 Dev Module](https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/boards/espressif32/esp32dev.html):

```
[env:esp32dev]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32dev
```

If your first try doesn't work, it's safe to try another.